# Why is my random password generator generating more than however many characters I need it to?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a random password generator with JavaScript and it is generating more characters than needed. I will explain after showing code:

```js
function gen() {
  var symbol = document.getElementById("symbolsCB");
  var number = document.getElementById("numbersCB");
  var upper = document.getElementById("uppersCB");
  var length = document.getElementById("numberOfChars").value;
  var op = document.getElementById("outputBox");
  var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (symbol.checked == true) {
      var symbols = ["?", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", ",", ".", "+", "=", "[", "]", "{", "}", ";", ":", "<", ">"];
      symbols.push.apply(list, symbols);
      let char = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
      op.value = op.value + char;
    }
    if (number.checked == true) {
      var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
      numbers.push.apply(list, numbers);
      let char = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
      op.value = op.value + char;
    }
    if (upper.checked == true) {
      var uppers = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
      uppers.push.apply(list, uppers);
      let char = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
      op.value = op.value + char;
    }
    if (symbol.checked == false && number.checked == false && upper.checked == false) {
      let char = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
      op.value = op.value + char;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="numbers" id="numbersCB" class="cb">
<label for="numbers"> Include Numbers </label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="uppers" id="uppersCB" class="cb">
<label for="uppers"> Include Uppercase Letters </label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="symbols" id="symbolsCB" class="cb">
<label for="symbols"> Include Symbols (@, #, $, %) </label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="numberOfChars" name="numberOfChars" placeholder="Length of password...">
<br/>
<button onclick="gen()"> Generate Random Password </button>

<input type="text" id="outputBox" name="outputBoxName" disabled="disabled">
```

For example, If I put 7 for the length and check all 3 boxes, I will get 21. And, if i put 10 for length and check 2 boxes, 20 characters appear. You get the pattern. Please explain why it's happening and please tell me how to fix it. Thank you

Comment: actually, now I know the problem. Can you all just tell me how to solve itt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that on each pass through the for loop you check if the checkboxes are set, and for each set checkbox, you update the list and add a character to the password. Instead, test the checkboxes before the loop and update your list based on them; then generate a single character in each pass through the loop.

```js
function gen() {
  var symbol = document.getElementById("symbolsCB");
  var number = document.getElementById("numbersCB");
  var upper = document.getElementById("uppersCB");
  var length = document.getElementById("numberOfChars").value;
  var op = document.getElementById("outputBox");
  op.value = '';
  var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  if (symbol.checked == true) {
    var symbols = ["?", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", ",", ".", "+", "=", "[", "]", "{", "}", ";", ":", "<", ">"];
    symbols.push.apply(list, symbols);
  }
  if (number.checked == true) {
    var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
    numbers.push.apply(list, numbers);
  }
  if (upper.checked == true) {
    var uppers = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
    uppers.push.apply(list, uppers);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let char = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
    op.value = op.value + char;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="numbers" id="numbersCB" class="cb">
<label for="numbers"> Include Numbers </label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="uppers" id="uppersCB" class="cb">
<label for="uppers"> Include Uppercase Letters </label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="symbols" id="symbolsCB" class="cb">
<label for="symbols"> Include Symbols (@, #, $, %) </label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="numberOfChars" name="numberOfChars" placeholder="Length of password...">
<br/>
<button onclick="gen()"> Generate Random Password </button>

<input type="text" id="outputBox" name="outputBoxName" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm assuming this exercise is purely academic. This isn't a good way to generate passwords, because the random algorithm **isn't cryptographically secure**.

Instead of going through each group and appending characters - I'd create a list of all of the characters you plan to use, then select randomly from that list.

So in psuedo code, you'd be looking at something like this;

```
var validCharacters = [];
if (includeUppercase) {
    validCharacters.push.apply(validCharacters, ["A", "B", "..."]);
}
if (includeLowercase) {
    validCharacters.push.apply(validCharacters, ["a", "b", "..."]);
}
// ...
```

Then once the list is fully populated - do your for loop to select random characters from it like you currently are.